# Spring WS in Google App Engine

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, jetty, spring-ws

Is it possible to use Spring WS in GAE? I am developing a small project with Spring + Hibernate which runs on Jetty. I am using Spring WS to make my app interact with SOAP clients. I want to seamlessly deploy my app on GAE. Does Spring WS work on GAE? If it does not, are there any PAAS solutions which support Spring WS? Please advice.

Thanks.